# Go rollback transactions in service level

Tags: go, orm, backend

I use an interface to interact with my entGO repository. But I have a problem: I'm using the CRUD model to design my repository, and I want to know if I need to use Transaction to create a user and then generate a token. I need to do that with Transaction to roll back in case of failure. My problem is I can only use my client at a repository level. What is the best manner to handle the transaction? Do I need to create a custom function to handle the Transaction or design my function to take transaction parameters? Here is an example of what I have:

```golang
// mariaUserRepository is data/repository implementation
// of service layer UserRepository
type mariaUserRepository struct {
    Client *ent.Client
}

// NewUserRepository is a factory for initializing User Repositories
func NewUserRepository(client *ent.Client) models.UserRepository {
    return &mariaUserRepository{
        Client: client,
    }
}

// Create reaches out to database entGO api
func (r *mariaUserRepository) Create(ctx context.Context, u *ent.User) error {

    // check if a user already exist
    check, err := r.Client.User.
        Query().
        Where(user.Email(u.Email)).Exist(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        utils.Logger.Info("Error when checking user",
            zap.String("email", u.Email),
            zap.Error(err),
        )
        return handle_errors.NewInternal()
    }
    if check {
        err := handle_errors.NewConflict("email", u.Email)
        utils.Logger.Info("Error when Register User",
            zap.String("email", u.Email),
            zap.Error(err),
        )
        return err
    }

    if u, err = r.Client.User.
        Create().
        SetFirstName(u.FirstName).
        SetLastName(u.LastName).
        SetEmail(u.Email).
        SetGender(u.Gender).
        SetUserType(u.UserType).
        SetPasswordHash(u.PasswordHash).
        Save(ctx); err != nil {
        utils.Logger.Info("Error when create user",
            zap.Any("User", u),
            zap.Error(err),
        )
        return handle_errors.NewInternal()
    }
    return nil
}
```

My problem come from the comment that say to implement rollback in case of failure.

````golang
    err := h.UserService.Signup(ctx, u)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to sign up user: %v\n", err.Error())
        c.JSON(apperrors.Status(err), gin.H{
            "error": err,
        })
        return
    }

    // create token pair as strings
    tokens, err := h.TokenService.NewPairFromUser(ctx, u, "")

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to create tokens for user: %v\n", err.Error())

        // may eventually implement rollback logic here
        // meaning, if we fail to create tokens after creating a user,
        // we make sure to clear/delete the created user in the database

        c.JSON(apperrors.Status(err), gin.H{
            "error": err,
        })
        return
    }
    ```
````

Comment: https://audrenbdb.fr/posts/repo-transaction/ maybe this answers your interrogation?

Comment: It's not that because in his example, it is only implementation in the repository layer, and I'm looking at the Service layer

Comment: perhaps the post is not clear enough, but this is indeed a way to make transaction from the service layer. Check the latest cold block from the article. The `PurchaseOrder` from the service handles an atomic operation combining `SaveOrder` and `SaveAccount`.

Comment: You should inject db as parameter in every `mariaUserRepository` function from your service layer.

Example using gorm:
`func (r *mariaUserRepository) Create(ctx context.Context, tx *gorm.DB, u *ent.User) error {`

And you could init the transaction in the service layer and manage it from there.

Comment: Yes, I better understand how it work, @AdoRen your explanation is ok now